# twitter bootstrap checkboxes html doesn't function properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason when I generate this using jquery to fill in my table. The checkboxes don't come out as they should with twitter bootstrap.

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" name="CheckGroup1" value="somenumber"; />
    </label>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
  <label class="radio">
    <input id= "box" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="somenumber" />
  </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Two secs, i'll grab my crystal ball... whats the issue exactly, what do you mean by "dont come out as they should"

Comment: they're just normal checkboxes and radio buttons not the bootstrap kind. and i've applied the css properly b/c the tables come out correctly with bootstrap

Comment: An example ([**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/)) would be very helpful to actually see / demonstrate what is going wrong.

Comment: Bootstrap does not alter checkboxes and radio buttons; they simply set values for padding, vertical alignment, etc. What  are you expecting the result to be? Also, your jsfiddle demo doesn't appear to work properly; no checkboxes or radio buttons appear in the rendered HTML

Comment: Ah yeah there were some errors I made in the jsfiddle but uhm it doesnt change the appearance? Like on the site it changes from normal checkboxes to bubbly sorts of checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reviewing the fiddle you posted in Google Chrome, 
and then using Chrome's debugger (F12), 
and then viewing the Console in the debugger, 
you may find the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

The syntax error points to here:

```
attributes = ['blah", "blah", "blah", "blah...
```

So in the very first `blah` item in the array, the enclosing quotes are mixed: single quote and double quote.
But if you change this to:

```
attributes = ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah...
```

...then your html should render properly, as with the following fork of your fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/cykm5/4/

Is this what you meant when you said, "The checkboxes don't come out as they should..."?